# I am Unable to authenticate CKAN 2.7.2 using oauth2 on http

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fiware, ckan, oauth2client

I am using CKAN 2.7.2 .

I have added the following configurations in my development.ini file of ckan

```
ckan.oauth2.authorization_endpoint = https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/authorize
ckan.oauth2.token_endpoint = https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_url = https://account.lab.fiware.org/user
ckan.oauth2.client_id = xyz
ckan.oauth2.client_secret = xyz 
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_user_field = abc
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_mail_field =  abc@gmail.com
```

Also, have exported the following while running ckan using paster serve :

```
export OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=True
```

Also, I have added an application in fiware.lab also with callback URL where the CKAN instance is running (i.e a private IP of 172.30.66.XX type running on port 5000)

And when I click on Login,i get redirect to fiware lab login page and after logging in i get the following error

```
{"state": "eyJjYW1lX2Zyb20iOiAiL2Rhc2hib2FyZCJ9", "error": "mismatching_redirect_uri"} (HTTP 400)
```

If anyone could please help me in this. It would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the redirect URL attached by CKAN is not the same as the one you have registered as callback URL when registering the application in the IDM.

Ensure that the callback URL you have included in the IDM is:

http://YOUR_CKAN_INSTANCE/oauth2/callback

The URL must match exactly (so no trailing backslash)

Comment: I have changed the callback URL provided above in the IDM,But when i am redirected back to CKAN, I get the message *Scope has changed from " " to "all_info" .* 
Am i missing on something? or is it incorrect ?

Comment: It is just that you need to configure the plugin setting:
**ckan.oauth2.scope = all_info** since the FIWARE IDM do not support scopes

Comment: Hi @Francisco , I added the same configuration which i used in IDM(which is working fine by updating the fields as you told,Thanks!), but when I am using the same configuration for IDP(WSO2 Identity server).I get a message _Invalid client (Client authentication failed)_ .If you can suggest me where I am going wring in this case.(Also,the callback url and scope are same).

Comment: Probably is an issue with the structure of user information, since different IDMs use different formats. There are some configuration settings that enable you to specify the fields that include the user info (user name, email, etc)